# Can I install Matlab on my external HDD drive?

Tags: matlab

I am running Win 7 on my laptop. My hard drive is very small 128 G, and I haven't storage enough to install Matlab on local partition. Can I install Matlab on my external hard and use it without any problems?

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can install it on your external drive. A better question you should ask yourself, is this a USB 2.0 external drive (vs 3.0)? In which case, will you be satisfied with the performance of it? If you answered yes to the last question, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to do so.